# Array in Array Php Foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, explode

i have array in array foreach.

I did not add html codes into foreach. Just to show an example. I've been working for 2 hours. Please help me.

My array explode code;

```
string = "Deri Renk|kırmızı-siyah-beyaz-sarı-lacivert,kadife Renk|kırmızı-sarı";
$delimiters = Array(",",":","|","-");

$res = multiexplode($delimiters,$string);

foreach ($res as $val) {
echo $val;
};
```

My Array Output;

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => HEAD
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => item1
                        [1] => item2
                        [2] => item3
                        [3] => item4
                        [4] => item5
                    )

            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => HEAD 2
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => item1
                        [1] => item2
                    )
            )
    )
);
```

I want to print as follows. It's a simple operation, but I could not do it because php is a bit of information. ;

```
<div>
<h1>HEAD</h1>
<ul>
<li>item1</li>
<li>item2</li>
<li>item3</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div>
<h1>HEAD</h1>
<ul>
<li>item1</li>
<li>item2</li>
<li>item3</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

my multiexplode function this:

```
function multiexplode ($delimiters,$string) {
$ary = explode($delimiters[0],$string);
array_shift($delimiters);
if($delimiters != NULL) {
    foreach($ary as $key => $val) {
        $ary[$key] = multiexplode($delimiters, $val);
    }
}
return  $ary;
}
```

Comment: So make a `foreach`, what's the problem?

Comment: Multiexplode is not a standard function. Please include the function in code

Comment: I am writing array values in foreach. The result is blank.

Comment: The array output is a bit confusing as it bears no relation to the input.

Comment: Ok.. include the multiexplode in **question** not in comments.

Comment: @NigelRen that's what I also think. That's why I asked for multiexplode, if it's the standard multiexplode from manual there is no way that is the output.

Comment: I've added a topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've gone for the option of rewriting it so that it's simpler to use.  This involves removing the need for the `multiexplode()` function and instead doing this specifically for the string format involved.

So first break down by `,` then split this up to header and content.

```
$input = "Deri Renk|kırmızı-siyah-beyaz-sarı-lacivert,kadife Renk|kırmızı-sarı";
$list = explode(",", $input);
$list1 = [];
foreach( $list as $item )   {
    list($key,$data) = explode("|", $item);
    $list1[$key] = explode("-", $data);
}

foreach ( $list1 as $heading=>$out )  {
    echo "<div><h1>$heading</h1><ul>";
    echo "<li>".implode("</li><li>",$out)."</li>";
    echo "</ul></div>";
}
```

The output is...

```
<div>
    <h1>Deri Renk</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>kırmızı</li>
        <li>siyah</li>
        <li>beyaz</li>
        <li>sarı</li>
        <li>lacivert</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>
    <h1>kadife Renk</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>kırmızı</li>
        <li>sarı</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I like the new array structure! +1

Comment: There is a small problem in the code. Each title must be in a separate div. Thanks dude.

Comment: @CelalYeşil I don't understand the problem, it does what you say, see here; https://3v4l.org/uBVIS

Comment: I had missed a close `>` in the `</ul>` tag which may have thrown it out a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I have not included the html either but added comments to give you a guideline where to place it.

You need to loop all the levels of your array.
Your loop only loops the first level and there is no values there only arrays that can't be echoed.

```
foreach ($res as $sub) {
    foreach($sub[0] as $key => $item){
        // If key is 0 it's the head, else it's the items
        if($key == 0){
            echo "  "; // this is HEAD
        }
        foreach($item as $val){
            echo $val . "\n"; // this is ITEMS
        }
    }
};
```

See it working here: https://3v4l.org/sg4AR

Comment: I couldn't accept the edit, it did not include echoing the HEAD. So it would make my code not working as expected

Answer (score 0):

If your array is consistent:

```
$html = '';
foreach ($array as $value) {
  $html .= '<div>';
  $head = $value[0][0][0];
  $html .= '<h1>'.$head.'</h1>';
  $html .= '<ul>';
  foreach ($value[0][1] as $item) {
    $html .= '<li>'.$item.'</li>';
  }
  $html .= '</ul>';
  $html .= '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code;

```
$string = "HEAD|item1-item2-item3-item4-item5,HEAD 2|item1-item2";
$delimiters = array(",",":","|","-");
$res = multiexplode($delimiters,$string);

// Preparing HTML
$html = '';
foreach ($res as $val) {
    $header = $val[0][0][0];
    $items = $val[0][1];
    $html .= '<div><h1>'.$header.'</h1><ul>';
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $html .= '<li>'.$item.'</li>';
    }    
    $html .= '</ul></div>';    
};
echo $html;
```